# How to properly set up the condition in a do-while loop (C)

Tags: c

While finishing an assignment I had to figure out how to check if the first two numbers of an input are of certain combination. While I have the idea what to do, I seem to have an error in the first part of my code.
I wanted to ''isolate'' the first two numbers by dividing the input by 10 while the input is more than 2.
I wrote this block of code

```
do
    {
        card_number = card_number / 10;
    }
    while (card_number > 2);
```

I was expecting the result to be '45' for example, but everytime I run the code and use printf to see the result, the only thing coming back is a zero.

Comment: I've no idea what you want or what your problem is. Please reformulate your problem and question. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Ideally one which demonstrates your problem without requiring input.

Comment: `card_number / 10` looks like integer division (and subsequent rounding error), but not sure because you have not shown enough code.

Comment: An input of _what_? Integer? String?

Comment: If you divide an integer between 2 and 9 by 10 you get 0. For 10 to 19 you get 1. Are you sure that you get a 0 if you start with 100?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to isolate the first two digits of `card_number`, then your condition should check that the **length** of the number is 2, not the **value**. Another way to do this is to keep dividing by 10 if the value is greater than 100.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int card_number = 450;
  printf("%i\n", card_number);

  while(card_number > 100) {
    card_number = card_number / 10;
  }

  printf("%i\n", card_number);
  return 0;
}
```

(Since you're trying to isolate the first two digits, I assume the value does start out greater than 100.)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated to "isolate" first 2 digits...**

I think this is what you're asking ...

```
int main() {
  //TEST CASES = Longer and Shorter than 2 digits
  //Comment and uncomment c_num as required for testing both cases

  long c_num = 1234567812345678;

  //long c_num = 12;

  int count = 0;

  long n = c_num;
  long long n1 = c_num, n2 = c_num; // n2 will hold the first two digits. 

  while (n) {
    n2 = n1;
    n1 = n;
    n /= 10;
  }
  printf("The first 2 numbers of the long are %lld\n", n2);

  /* Run loop till num is greater than 0 */
  do {
    /* Increment digit count */
    count++;
    /* Remove last digit of 'num' */
    c_num /= 10;
  }
  while (c_num != 0);

  printf("Total digits: %d\n", count);

  if (count > 2) {
    /* Do work */
    printf("Total digits is more than 2");
  } else {
    /*Do other work */
    printf("Total digits is NOT more than 2");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [No images please](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10669875)